# Cannot get Android Market to exclude small-screen phones for this app

Tags: android, android-manifest

This app was originally released erroneously supporting all screen sizes due to a manifest error. That has now seemingly been cleaned up, but there is still a continuous parade of angry users with Samsung Intercepts or similar LDPI, small-screen devices who were somehow able to purchase and install the app. Here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="..."
  android:versionCode="7"
  android:versionName="1.06">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

    <supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="false"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"/>
    <activity android:name="..."
    </activity>

</application>
```

The "..." indicates anonymized content. Does anybody have an idea of what is causing the Android Market to still make this available to small screens?

Answer (score 1):

support-screens tag should be put outside the application tags, similar to this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..."
android:versionCode="7"
android:versionName="1.06">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon"   
android:debuggable="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
<activity android:name="..."
</activity>

</application>
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"/>
```

Comment: Definitely this was a problem. Now that is has been fixed (for a quite some time, eliminating the possibility of caching issues), the app remains available on small-screened devices!? Could it be that by targeting all screens initially, it will just keep that setting no matter how the manifest changes in subsequent releases?